# Lax pairs in an abstract formalism

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, integrable-systems

I am reading *Integrals of Nonlinear Equations of
Evolution and Solitary Waves* by Peter Lax and I'm having a hard time. The methods are pioneering, of course, but Lax does not bother much to provide precise explanations: he sticks to the PDE *Weltanschauung* and simply differentiates and integrates all the way through. This is fully ok, as long his results are groundbreaking and he's interested in a very specific PDE (KdV on $\mathbb R$, in this case) where his ideas work.

However, things break down soon if one tries to apply Lax' ideas to other examples; this is especially the case if one thinks of PDEs on bounded domains, where boundary conditions matter and make it tricky to figure out what's the precise meaning of a commutator.

So I was wondering whether there is some good reference about an abstract approach to the Lax pair idea. I'm ideally thinking of something along the lines of:

> Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, $D_1,D_2$ subspaces of $H$ that are
>    densely and compactly embedded in $H$, $\mathbb R_+\ni t\mapsto L(t)\in
>  {\mathcal L}(D_1,H)$ be a $C^1$-family such that each $L(t)$ is
>    self-adjoint as an operator on $H$ with domain $D_1$, $\mathbb R_+\ni t\mapsto P(t)\in {\mathcal L}(D_2,H)$ be a $C^1$-family of operators that generate an invertible evolution family on $H$ ...

and so on. Basically, what I'm looking for is a precise translation of the idea of Lax pairs to Hilbert space theory.

Comment: Exactly. The whole literature on these hierarchies is in disastrous shape from a mathematician's point of view. Not only is much of it non-rigorous, but if you actually tried to a give careful version, you'd probably get an outcry from a crowd of people claiming "I did this 50 years ago." If the precise setting doesn't matter much to you, then my recommendation is to focus on the Toda hierarchy, where global existence and uniqueness actually hold (obviously this is totally out of reach in the continuous case), and is it totally immodest if I point out that I recently posted a paper (...)

Comment: (cont'd) which certainly clarified a few things for me, though it may not do the same for others: https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.00503

Comment: That's an interesting question. Is there a single example of a PDE on a bounded domain which is known to be integrable, say the NLS with Cauchy BC?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: Periodic potentials are of this type. The proper setting here is really finite gap potentials, and there's a huge literature on those (these form finite-dimensional invariant tori, so give you finite-dimensional integrable systems, on which various communities have descended like locusts).

Comment: @AmirSagiv On a much more modest level, transport equations are of course integrable; random evolutions à la Griego-Hersh on bounded domains are sometimes integrable, too; and both heat and wave equations on compact quantum graphs are also integrable, at least in many relevant cases and under most usual boundary conditions.

Comment: @ChristianRemling and Delio,  these are both great examples. Do we have a nonlinear PDE, potential-less equation (such as KG, SG, KdV, NLS), on a bounded domain, which is integrable?

Comment: @AmirSagiv Well, for instance, the Burgers equation with precisely those BCs that arise from the Hopf-Cole-Transformation of a heat equation with, say, Dirichlet or Neumann b.c. 
But it feels like cheating, you're probably thinking of something different.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo you're right. I want to ask - How do we know that there is a nonlinear Lax pairs for *any* nonlinear PDE with BC? Maybe the introduction of BCs destroys integrability?

Comment: @AmirSagiv That's exactly the point. Since Lax does not explain what he means by "commutator" (what domain of the commutator should be taken? the maximal domain? an intersection of two cores?), it is not clear whether one has to make sure that the Lax pair formalism still makes sense.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo: In some cases, one can do this by hand. For example, the periodic (or finite gap) potentials could be viewed as potentials on $\mathbb R$, by extension, and then one can use the whole line Lax operators. Periodic potentials are invariant because the flows commute with the shift. Similarly, Dirichlet boundary conditions for Jacobi matrices can be implemented by setting the corresponding coefficient $a=0$, and again these sets are invariant under the (whole line) flow, so we can again reduce matters to the original (whole line) Lax operators.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Sure. But, if you want to approach it from a different angle, I would have looked for integrable, nonlinear, bounded-domain system. If no one has ever been able to show in *any other way* such a system, that's a strong indication (only an indication, not an answer) that the problem is not with Lax' formalism, but an essential problem to integrability.

Comment: The two-volume book *Soliton equations and their algebro-geometric solutions* ( see http://cambridge.org/0521753074 for volume 1 dealing with the PDE case ) is very much on the rigorous side of things .

Comment: @AmirSagiv You're probably right. My (naive?) intuition is that things can get interesting in "boundary cases", like, PDEs on bounded domains with periodic BCs. To treat those, a general abstract theory would come in handy.